# Angular 7 Testing Karma Error : Can't resolve all parameters for WebStorageService: (?)

Tags: angular, angular7, karma-jasmine

WebStorageService works fine in component , but when trying to test in Karma gives below exception.

**Error: Can't resolve all parameters for WebStorageService: (?).**

Below My Specs code

```
import {LOCAL_STORAGE} from 'angular-webstorage-service';
import { WebStorageService } from 'angular-webstorage-service';

fdescribe('MyComponent', () => {
    let component: MyComponent;
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<MyComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {  
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        RouterTestingModule,
        FormsModule,       
      ],
      declarations: [
        MyComponent
      ],
      providers: [                
        WebStorageService                
      ],
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));
```

Comment: Can you add the code for component html and ts file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are more than one way to do that. I would recommend to work with stubs for the WebStorageService. This means the service is not executed but some mocking code you added to the spec. For testing the component it might be better to not execute the service but deliver viable demo data.

First define the stub:

```
exort const webStoreageServiceStub = {
 function1() {
  return something;
 }
 function2() {
  return something;
 }
 .
 .
 .
}
```

Then provide it:

```
  providers: [                
    { provide: WebStorageService, useValue: webStoreageServiceStub}               
  ]
```

You might also use

```
schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA]
```

Here everything added to your code.

```
exort const webStoreageServiceStub = {
 function1() {
  return something;
 }
 function2() {
  return something;
 }
}


describe('MyComponent', () => {
let component: MyComponent;
let fixture: ComponentFixture<MyComponent>;

beforeEach(async(() => {  
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  imports: [
    RouterTestingModule,
    FormsModule,       
  ],
  declarations: [
    MyComponent
  ],
  providers: [                
    { provide: WebStorageService, useValue: webStoreageServiceStub}               
  ],
  schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA]
})
.compileComponents();
}));
```

Comment: code updated as suggested. throws below error.Failed:   StaticInjectorError(DynamicTestModule)[MyComponent -> InjectionToken LOCAL_STORAGE]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[MyComponent -> InjectionToken LOCAL_STORAGE]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for InjectionToken LOCAL_STORAGE!

Comment: Is LOCAL_STORAGE used anywhere in the test code? If not then remvoe the import.

Comment: My component Constructor                                                                        constructor(@Inject(LOCAL_STORAGE) private storage: WebStorageService)

Comment: I am not sure but I think you have to make a stub for LOCAL_STORAGE also.

Comment: Even after removed LOCAL_STORAGE import in specs throws the same error. maybe it needs to add in Providers section in specs file

Comment: Yes, add it the same way like the service.

Comment: it worked after added it to Provider section.                                                                  { provide: LOCAL_STORAGE, useValue: ' '}  ,